# Ajax code with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have null experience in web programming, yet I am testing a simple add on to work with my app.
On the webpage I display a number of rows. Each row has an editable field that the user needs to input.

Once he inputs it, I want to launch PHP code to run an SQL statement. My initial try worked, yet the page of the php script was opened. I would like somehow the php to run in the background and the user stays on the same page.

Looking online I found that I need to have something like the following:

```
<script>
function DataChanged(mId,mQ){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Change Id='+mId+'Q='+mQ ;
        $.ajax({
                url: 'submitChange.php?Id=5'
                });

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Arrived here?';
}
</script>
```

The text field is changed to:

> Change Id=...

yet the script isn't running and text isn't becoming

> "Arrived here?"

I ran the submitChange.php?Id=5 separately and it worked, so I am guessing my error is from the script above. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You're using a jQuery method, have you loaded jQuery _before_ ? Also, check on jQuery docs for a more complete code

Comment: Please also post your PHP-Code.

Comment: @Prior what for? He says the php part works when called directly, that means (and the code shows it) the ajax part has issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuerys AJAX is **Asynchroneous**. This means that at the time you are doing the

`document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Arrived here?';`

The AJAX-Request was not yet done. Please consult the [API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) from jQuery.

You will have to do it like this:
(The first parameter of the anonymous function is the result got from the call)

```
<script>
function DataChanged(mId,mQ){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Change Id='+mId+'Q='+mQ ;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submitChange.php?Id=5'
        }).done(function(result) {
             document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Arrived here?' + result;
        });
}
</script>
```

As you are already using jQuery, why not use their selectors instead of `document.getElementById`?

```
<script>
function DataChanged(mId,mQ){
        $('#demo').html('Change Id='+mId+'Q='+mQ);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submitChange.php?Id=5'
        }).done(function(result) {
             $('#demo').html('Arrived here?' + result);
        });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use jQuery `$.ajax` to achieve this, what you are looking for is an [XMLHTTPRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must specify the type of ajax query:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Change Id='+mId+'Q='+mQ ;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'submitChange.php',
  data: {
    Id: 5,
  },
  success: function (result) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Arrived here?';
  }
});
```

or

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Change Id='+mId+'Q='+mQ ;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'submitChange.php?Id=5',
  success: function (result) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Arrived here?';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to include the jquery library into you document
Example:

There is an example for you task.

```
function DataChanged(mId,mQ){
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Change Id='+mId+'Q='+mQ ;
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", // type of request [get/post], you need get            
        url: 'submitChange.php?Id=5',   
        async: true, // this is the flag to run ajax request Asynchroneously, you don't need to wait.
        success : function(data)
        {
            // "data" is the text from request
            // there the code for execution after receiving an unswer from request
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Arrived here?';
        }
    });
}
```